# Internationalization for Dates in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, date, internationalization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to translate Dates in API's(**[Django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)**), 
well as of now *Internationalization and localization* is working for all the other things but i am stuck at Dates.

There is only English and French language and also i have restarted server few times but not able to get dates in *FR*  as you can see i have used [Rosetta](http://django-rosetta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)[image]

**Example code :**

```
@staticmethod
def get_start_date(obj):
    return obj.start_date.strftime("%d %B, %Y")
```

when lang code is **en**
O/P is :

**start_date": "01 January, 2016"**

but when lang code is **fr** expected result:

**start_date": "01 Janvier, 2016"**

still it is showing in english

*settings.py*
   i have successfully added basic settings still for your information

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',

USE_L10N = True
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: facing the same issue..have you got a solution meanwhile?

Comment: Tried but didn't found the proper solution. Don't waste much time, try any other quick fix. I did fixed using jquery. @MihaiZamfir

Comment: Thanks. I ended with a custom solution as well, but I thought I would have been nicer to have an native solution

Answer (score 2):

It's hack too, but helping. Add this in Rest view:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "ru_RU.utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

For localizing the dates, you need to use the django-babel package that can easily be integrated with the django locale middleware.

Check the documentation below.
http://django-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/